# Add Ellipsis to pagination row

Tags: jquery, razor, pagination

I have a code that paginates a table but I am trying to add ellipsis ... to it so that it would go 1 2 3 ... 15 instead of listing all 15 pages. How can I achieve that?

```
function RowPaging(numPerPage) {
    $('.tabledata').each(function () {
        var currentPage = 0;
        var $table = $(this);
        $table.bind('repaginate', function () {
            $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
        });
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
        var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
        var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
        var $pager = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
        for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
            $('<span class="page-number"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
                newPage: page
            }, function (event) {
                currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
                $table.trigger('repaginate');
                $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
        }
        $pager.insertAfter($table).find('span.page-number:first').addClass('active');

    });
}
```

Comment: Inside the `for (var page = 0`.... you could conditionally check if the `page <= 3` then either display the span or not (display "..."). But that's a static solution. You'll need to perform some more logic if you want ... 5 6 7 ... where 6 is the current page, etc..

Comment: Is there a good syntax that could help me do that?

Comment: You would need to provide more context- I'm not sure what the data source is, nor where in the pipeline you are. Is data being returned via an ajax call, and you're processing it client-side? Without knowing more it would be really difficult to give you more specific answers. That being said, I'm assuming razor means you're working in ASP.NET- it might be easier to implement paging on the server side and only send a smaller dataset to the client.

Comment: Here is a link regarding paging in ASP.NET MVC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application